# dynamically retriving the x,y position of an element in canvas

Tags: silverlight

I have this code

```
        <Canvas x:Name="SampleCanvas" Background="#F5F7F9"  MouseLeftButtonDown="brdMovable_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="brdMovable_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="brdMovable_MouseMove" Height="570" Width="875">                    
         <chartingToolkit:Chart  x:Name="mcChart" Loaded="mcChart_Loaded"  Width="400" Height="250" Canvas.Left="190" Canvas.Top="5" MouseLeftButtonDown="brdMovable_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                             Background="LightSteelBlue">
                        <chartingToolkit:Chart.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"></ScaleTransform>
                        </chartingToolkit:Chart.RenderTransform>
                        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
                            <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Title="Experience"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=ModelName}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding  Path=SaleCount}">
                            </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
                        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
                    </chartingToolkit:Chart> 
          </canvas>
```

Now i want to retrieve the canvas.Left position and canvas.Top positions of mcChart dynamically in codebehind.

How can i do that ?
Thanks.

Comment: +1 for providing clear description and Xaml :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Canvas.GetLeft(mcChart);
Canvas.GetTop(mcChart);
```

Comment: how can i get the scale transform property of the mcchart ie :<ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"> in the same way ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference to the mcChart. Then you can use the Attached Property accessor to get the current value:

```
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(mcChart);
double top  = Canvas.GetTop(mcChart);
```

To set the values in code:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(mcChart, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(mcChart, 100);
```

Comment: how can i get the scale transform property of the mcchart ie :<ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform">  in the same way ?

Comment: That's the mcChart.RenderTransform property value.